# POST - While Posting - Jquery - Not AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a typical post on my website.
It is not an ajax post. But do to the complexity, and number of var being posted, it is very slow. (Which is a problem in itself). However, for the time being, I want to create a loading window. Normally, with AJAX, I would use ajaxStart/ajaxStop and make something. Is there similar function for a standard post?

Comment: on post your page reloads? So when the form is posted, show a loader and leave it there; it will disappear on page reload.

Answer (score 2):

Can try something like this. The idea is to prevent a jQuery submit event, show a loader and after short delay to give time for loading indicator to be displayed,  trigger the native submit event

The submit process normally blocks the UI which is why the delay is added

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();//prevent jQuery event
     var form = this;    
     $('#loader').show();
     setTimeout(function(){
         form.submit();// submit native method
     },10);//minimal delay to allow browser to paint 
});
```